# lapply : Finding sum or mean instead of count

Tags: r

Suppose i have a data which looks like this

```
    Id Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode Supplier
1   1    A     2     5      8     1        X    K     John
2   1    A     2     6      9     2        X    K     John
3   1    A     2     5      8     3        X    K     John
4   2    B     2     4      6     1        X    L      Sam
5   2    B     2     3      4     2        X    L      Sam
6   2    B     2     5      7     3        X    L      Sam
7   3    C     2     5     11     1        X    M     John
8   3    C     2     5     11     2        X    L     John
9   3    C     2     5     11     3        X    K     John
10  4    D     2     8     10     1        Y    M     John
11  4    D     2     8     10     2        Y    K     John
12  4    D     2     5      7     3        Y    K     John
13  5    E     2     5      9     1        Y    M      Sam
14  5    E     2     5      9     2        Y    L      Sam
15  5    E     2     5      9     3        Y    M      Sam
16  6    F     2     4      7     1        Z    M     Kyle
17  6    F     2     5      8     2        Z    L     Kyle
18  6    F     2     5      8     3        Z    M     Kyle
```

I am interested in finding out under each `category`(X,Y,Z) which `supplier` used which `Mode` and made how much `Profit`(can be sum or mean).

```
lapply(split(df, df$Category), function(x) table(as.character(x$Supplier), x$Mode))
```

This command works to find number of supplier under each Mode for each Category but how to modify it so it can give total and mean Profit made.

Edit 1: Expected Output

Category X

```
        Mode
Supplier      K      L      M
   John       36     11     11
   Sam        0      17      0
   Kyle       0      0      0
```

Category Y

```
        Mode
Supplier      K      L      M
   John       17     0      10
   Sam        0      9      18
   Kyle       0      0      0
```

Category Z

This output is for sum of profit.

Thanks

Comment: @akrun did it for sum of profit.

Answer (score 1):

For simple cross-tabulation with the sum, you can use `xtabs()`.  With three categories we get back an array of three dimensions.

```
( xt <- xtabs(Profit ~ Supplier + Mode + Category, df) )
# , , Category = X
#
#         Mode
# Supplier  K  L  M
#     John 36 11 11
#     Kyle  0  0  0
#     Sam   0 17  0
#
# , , Category = Y
#
#         Mode
# Supplier  K  L  M
#     John 17  0 10
#     Kyle  0  0  0
#     Sam   0  9 18
#
# , , Category = Z
#
#         Mode
# Supplier  K  L  M
#     John  0  0  0
#     Kyle  0  8 15
#     Sam   0  0  0
```

To view this array without rows that are all zero, we can do

```
apply(xt, 3, function(x) x[rowSums(x) != 0, , drop = FALSE])
```

For the mean (or sum, or any other function), `tapply()` will also return an array.

```
with(df, tapply(Profit, list(Supplier, Mode, Category), mean))
```

You could also just use `aggregate()`

```
aggregate(Profit ~ Category + Mode + Supplier, df, mean)
```

Comment: But it will combine profit of all categories for a supplies, how to get a separate table for each category (X,Y,Z) which shows mean or sum of profit for each supplier under each Mode?

Comment: i have written expected output for sum of profit. Maybe i will want an output which omit the rows which have only 0, e.g 3rd row for Category X and Y.